# Annotate plot with geom_circle(scale of x and y are different)

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am trying to annotate a specific area of data with `geom_circle()`, but the package drew an ellipse instead of a circle; It seems `inherit.aes` argument isn’t helping me to adjust the scale of the circle.

```
df = data.frame(index = 1:1000, data = runif(1000))
ggplot(df) + aes(x = index, y = data) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_circle(aes(x0=200, y0=0.4, r=3), inherit.aes=F)
```

[image]

I am expecting to get something like:

[image]

Comment: With those disparate x and y scales you want an oblate ellipse.

Answer (score 3):

You either need an ellipse, or a custom grob annotation:

```r
df = data.frame(index = 1:1000, data = runif(1000))

ggplot(df) + aes(x = index, y = data) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_ellipse(aes(x0 = 200, y0 = 0.4, a = diff(range(index)) * 0.1,
                   b = diff(range(data)) * 0.1, angle = 0), col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Will keep that in mind as an option to draw a circle.

Answer (score 3):

As you want to add an annotation I would suggest to switch to `ggforce::geom_mark_circle` instead of using `geom_circle` which according to the docs

> ... will only produce a true circle if ggplot2::coord_fixed() is used.

In contrast `ggforce::geom_mark_circle` is meant to

> annotate sets of points via circles.

and makes it easy to add the annotation via the `label` aes and offers a lot of options to style the annotation:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(index = 1:1000, data = runif(1000))

ggplot(df) +
  aes(x = index, y = data) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_mark_circle(aes(x = 200, y = 0.4, label = "Annotation"), 
                   radius = unit(15, "mm"), color = "red", size = 2, 
                   label.colour = "red", con.colour = NA, label.fill = NA,
                   label.buffer = unit(5, "mm"))
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df) +
  aes(x = index, y = data) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_mark_circle(aes(x = 200, y = 0.4, label = "Annotation"), 
                   radius = unit(15, "mm"), color = "red", size = 2, 
                   con.colour = "red", con.cap = unit(0, "mm"),
                   label.colour = "red", label.buffer = unit(5, "mm"))
```

[image]

Comment: Definitely the better option here.